# Listing only the files in a folder and inside its subfolders

Tags: files, find, utilities

Is there a linux command for getting only the files in a folder and inside its subfolders? I have used the `find` command, but it is displaying all the files and folders. I am executing this shell command using the php `exec()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the -type f option to get only files.

```
find /path_to_find -type f
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz.Is their any way to get the files that are modified after a date like `20-08-2011`

Comment: @THOmas: read the man page & search, this is very frequently asked (and answered)

Comment: @THOmas: man find. You can use -mtime, or you can  use touch to create a file with the time 20110820 and use -newer.